# ASP.NET Controller return variable View access

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I created in asp.net mvc the following data model:

```
public class DetailModel
{ 
public string name { get; set; }
public string value { get; set; }
public Highcharts chart { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I accumulate the data:

```
public ActionResult detail()
{
var viewModel = new DetailModel();

Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart") ....

viewModel.chart = chart;
viewModel.name = "test string";
viewModel.value = "1a"

return View(viewModel);
}
```

In the view model I want to have access to the vieModel Data but it will not work.

I have tried it with the following code:

```
<%: viewModel.value %>
```

or

```
<%: viewModel %>
```

or

```
@(Model)
```

Or is this the wrong way to hand over multiple values to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the View what kind of model that it should be expecting via a `@model` statement at the top of your View :

```
<!-- The fully qualified name may vary -->
@model YourProject.Models.DetailModel
```

Once you do this, you can reference any of the properties that are present on this model using `Model` as seen in the example below :

```
<!-- Referencing the name property -->
Name: @Model.name 
<!-- Referencing the name property -->
Value: @Model.value
<!-- You can access the properties of your chart as well -->
@Model.chart.YourPropertyHere
```

Answer (score 0):

you should determine your model like this

```
@model DetailModel
```

and you can access your model properties like this

```
@Model.name 

@Model.value
```